# How can we find a WooCommerce shop bottleneck? (only when cart is full)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Our WooComerce shop page become very very slow after putting some item into the cart.

How can we find the bottleneck?

We tried Blackfire.io Firefox extension but it aborts after a while.

We tried WP CLI Profile but it's unuseful if we can't fill the cart.

We tried query search but we can't find useful info there.

Ps: Interest installed plugins:

- WooCommerce,
- WooCommerce Cart
- WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts
- and our custom plugin.

Maybe the problem is the integration between these plugins but it seems impossible to find the origin.

Comment: Since it's the cart, try disabling the 'WooCommerce Cart' plugin and see if that changes things.  Considering that you've added a plugin specifically to work with the cart and the slow down is on the cart page, that'd be my first check.  You can also try disabling the plugins one by one to see if any of the others are the problem.

Comment: Go for the "Query Monitor Plugin" - it shows you literally every query.

Comment: Thank you. But I think it's not a query issue: it seems like a hook loop. I need a profiler.